# Enviando mensagem Java Socket

Tags: java, socket

Olá estou "tentando" fazer um server socket ate ai consegui mas não estou conseguindo fazer a comunicação entre os servidores.

Mas o mais estranha é o seguinte confira a print abaixo

[image: Server socket]

Mas o que esta acontecendo ao invés a mensagem sair em apenas uma frase esta "floodando" o console com as letras. A mensagem que deve ser enviado pro servidor seria "Jogador" mas o que esta retornando "J" "O" "G" "A" "D" "O" "R"

Sou iniciante nesse lance de socket. O modo que fiz para enviar a mensagem:

```
public void socketSendMensagem(String mensagem) {
    
    try {
        
        PrintStream saida = new PrintStream(cliente.getOutputStream());
        
        saida.println(mensagem);
        
        
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    
}
```

O que eu tive  que fazer para receber a mensagem completa:

```
        while(true) {
            System.out.println((char) cliente.getInputStream().read());
        }
```

Existe outro método

1. Relacionar o item

   melhor que esse?

Comment: Por favor, forneça um **[mcve]** para que possamos executar o codigo e ajudar a resolver o problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usa vírgula amigo, facilita a compreensão. Em todo caso, porque não tenta utilizar um Scanner para receber o getInputStream do seu socket? Ex:

```
Scanner entrada =  New Scanner(cliente.getInputStream());
System.out.println("Recebido: " + entrada.nextLine());
System.out.println("Eu tenho um vídeo explicando uma aplicação que utilizei socket, porque não confere? Talvez ajude: https://youtu.be/RkH4DmYH0hI");
```